Speeding up NIntegrate for some (simple?) trigonometry
I'm trying to determine the average distance you'd need to walk if you started at a point in a circle and walked to the edge of the circle, supposing I walked in a straight line and picked a random angle.
I'm extending it to various shapes, so please note, that the circle is just a simple example here, it could be any Region[], so answers which analytically solve for a circle are not helpful, nor is using symmetries of the circle to reduce the integration range. My general solution breaks down the edges for each shape, then integrates along them, like I have done for the circle here.
The solution and the integration below takes a long time! I don't know why - or if I have already reached what is reasonable.
This solution
ClearAll[px,py,y,x,L,r,m]

r=10/Sqrt[\[Pi]];
L=10/Sqrt[\[Pi]]*2;

regions = Region[Disk[{r,r},r]];

 
SignedVectorAngle[v1_List,v2_List]/;Length[v1]===2&&Length[v2]===2:=
If[VectorAngle[v1,v2]===Pi,Pi,RealSign[Last[Cross[Append[v1,0],Append[v2,0]]]]VectorAngle[v1,v2]];

(* note that y is used as the changing variable, and doesn't always correspond to the y coordinate*) 

distance1[px_?NumericQ,py_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ] :=EuclideanDistance[{px,py},{r+Sqrt[2 r y-y^2],y}];
distance2[px_?NumericQ,py_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ] :=EuclideanDistance[{px,py},{r-Sqrt[2 r y-y^2],y}];

angle1[px_,py_,y_]:= SignedVectorAngle[{r+Sqrt[2 r y-y^2]-px,y-py},{-px,0}]; 
angle2[px_,py_,y_]:= SignedVectorAngle[{r-Sqrt[2 r y-y^2]-px,y-py},{-px,0}];

(* accounts for change of variable from theta to y *) 
dangle1[px_?NumericQ,py_?NumericQ,y_]:=  Assuming[0<px<L&&0<py<L&&L>0&&y>0&&y\[Element]Reals,D[angle1[px,py,y],y]]/.{Abs->RealAbs};
dangle2[px_?NumericQ,py_?NumericQ,y_]:=  Assuming[0<px<L&&0<py<L&&L>0&&y>0&&y\[Element]Reals,D[angle2[px,py,y],y]]/.{Abs->RealAbs};

averagepathlength1[px_?NumericQ,py_?NumericQ]:= Assuming[0<px<L&&0<py<L&&L>0,NIntegrate[distance1[px,py,y]* dangle1[px,py,y],{y,L,0}]];
averagepathlength2[px_?NumericQ,py_?NumericQ]:= Assuming[0<px<L&&0<py<L&&L>0,NIntegrate[distance2[px,py,y]* dangle2[px,py,y],{y,0,L}]];


funcircle[pointx_?NumericQ,pointy_?NumericQ]:=
If[RegionMember[regions,{pointx,pointy}],
Return[(averagepathlength1[pointx,pointy]+averagepathlength2[pointx,pointy])/(2*Pi)] ;(* True *),
Return[0] ;(* False *)
]

This solves for one point
point = {6, 6}; (* this is near the centre of the circle *) 
Timing[funcircle[point[[1]], point[[2]]]]
Show[{Region[regions], Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[point]}]}]

(* output *) 
{0.561205, 5.63051}

So half a second per point!
Plotting the surface (badly) takes minutes, but you can see here where the shortest distances are, and as we'd expect, at the centre the distance is 5.64... = 10/Sqrt[\Pi].
DensityPlot[funcircle[pointx, pointy], {pointx, 0, L}, {pointy, 0, L}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]


And solving for the average can take many minutes - It gets progressively worse for more sided shapes. The circle can be solved in less than a minute, so it suitable for a MWE for this question.
Timing[NIntegrate[ N[funcircle[pointxi, pointyi]], {pointxi, pointyi} \[Element] 
   Disk[{r, r}, r],PrecisionGoal ->4]/100]

(*output*) 
{42.762, 4.78899}

I've tried solutions from here and here, to little avail.

A different point: SignedVectorAngle[v1_, v2_] := Mod[(ArcTan@@v2) - (ArcTan@@v1), 2π, -π] would probably be simpler than your case distinction and sign construction.

What should SignedVectorAngle[{1.2, 3.4}, -{1.2, 3.4}] be? I get 0..

Another efficient variant for SignedVectorAngle: sva[{a1_, a2_}, {b1_, b2_}] :=  With[{nn = Sqrt[(a1^2 + a2^2) (b1^2 + b2^2)]},   ArcTan[(a1 b1 + a2 b2)/nn, (-a2 b1 + a1 b2)/nn]]

I changed := to = so that the derivative is calculated once and for all (it takes a few seconds to simplify) and I added the assumption y != yp:
(*accounts for change of variable from theta to y*)
dangle1[px_?NumericQ, py_?NumericQ, y_] = 
  Assuming[
   0 < px < L && 0 < py < L && L > 0 && y > 0 && y \[Element] Reals &&
     y != py,
   D[angle1[px, py, y], y] /. {Abs -> RealAbs} /. 
     RealAbs[u_]^2 :> u^2 // Simplify];
dangle2[px_?NumericQ, py_?NumericQ, y_] = 
  Assuming[
   0 < px < L && 0 < py < L && L > 0 && y > 0 && y \[Element] Reals &&
     y != py,
   D[angle2[px, py, y], y] /. {Abs -> RealAbs} /. 
     RealAbs[u_]^2 :> u^2 // Simplify];

AbsoluteTiming[
 NIntegrate[
   N[funcircle[pointxi, pointyi]], {pointxi, pointyi} \[Element] 
    Disk[{r, r}, r], PrecisionGoal -> 4]/100]


(*  {1.25505, 4.78899}  *)

The assumption allows a piecewise result that was 0 if y != yp and Indeterminate if equal to be simplified to 0. It's a zero-measure change, and "shaved off" almost 18 seconds. The net savings was around 40 sec. for me.

The input checks and If[] statements slightly slow down evaluation. Maybe not enough to be worth refactoring. If you could be sure to call NIntegrate only on valid input, it should save a little time to get rid of them.

Adding // N to the end of the definitions for dangle1[] and dangle2[] saves an additional 25-30% in time. Or applying N[] to the defs. of r and L.
